# How to build query WHERE X OR HAVING Y

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, having

My data is a parent table named `sales` and a child table named `sale_lines`. I'd like to select all records from the `sales` table where `sale.customer_id=X` OR `SUM(sale_lines.total)>=Y`.

The `customer_id` condition will go in the `WHERE` clause and it makes sense to have the `SUM(sale_lines.total)>Y` in the `HAVING` clause. My problem is how to have a logical `OR` between the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses. Is this possible? If so, how?

I know how to do this with a sub-query, but I'm trying to develop an automated query generation solution and I'd like to avoid the complexity of dealing with sub-queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in the `having` clause:

```
select . . .
from . . .
group by s.customer_id, . . .
having s.customer_id = X or sum(s.total) > Y;
```

The query might look like:

```
select s.customer_id, sum(s.total)
from sales s
group by s.customer_id
having s.customer_id = X or sum(s.total) > Y;
```

Because of the `or`, you cannot filter before aggregation.

Actually, if you want the records from the sales table (and not the aggregations), then something like this is appropriate:

```
select s.*
from sales s
where s.customer_id = X or
      s.customer_id in (select s2.customer_id
                        from sales s2
                        group by s2.customer_id
                        having sum(s2.total) > Y
                       );
```